# PHP preg_match_all does not match everything

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

Consider the following code snippet:

```
$example = "DELIM1test1DELIM2test2DELIM1test3DELIM2test4"; // and so on

preg_match_all('/DELIM1(.*?)DELIM2(.*?)/', $example, $matches);
```

`$matches` array becomes:

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:2 [
    0 => "DELIM1test1DELIM2"
    1 => "DELIM1test3DELIM2"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    0 => "test1"
    1 => "test3"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [
    0 => ""
    1 => ""
  ]
]
```

As you can see, it fails to get `test2` and `test4`. Any reason why that happens and what could be a possible solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.*?` is non-greedy; if you have no constraint after it, it will match the minimum necessary: zero characters. You need a constraint after it to force it to match more than trivially. For example:

```
/DELIM1(.*?)DELIM2(.*?)(?=DELIM1|$)/
```

Answer (score 3):

Lazy subpatterns at the end of the patter match either 0 (`*?`) or 1 (`+?`) characters because they match as few as possible.

You can still use lazy matching and append a lookahead that will require a DELIM1 to appear after the value or the end of string:

```
/DELIM1(.*?)DELIM2(.*?)(?=$|DELIM1)/
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iP7wS0/1). It is very close in terms of performance with a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) (`DELIM1(.*?)DELIM2((?:(?!DELIM1).)*)` - [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iP7wS0/2)).

However, the best approach is to unroll it:

```
DELIM1(.*?)DELIM2([^D]*(?:D(?!ELIM1)[^D]*)*)
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/iP7wS0/3)

Answer (score 3):

preg_split would be better:

```
$example = "DELIM1test1DELIM2test2DELIM1test3DELIM2test4"; // and so on
$keywords = preg_split("/DELIM1|DELIM2/", $example,0,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($keywords);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test1
    [1] => test2
    [2] => test3
    [3] => test4
)
```

demo: http://ideone.com/s5nC0k

Answer (score 2):

Those values are OUTSIDE of your anchors, so they won't get matched. e.g. (with some extra spaces)

```
str:  DELIM1  test1  DELIM2         test2   DELIM1  test3  DELIM2        test4
pat:  DELIM1  (.*?)  DELIM2  (.*?)          DELIM1  (.*?)  DELIM2 (.*?) 
             match #1                                match #2
```

`(.*?)` is a non-greedy match, and can/will match a 0-length string. Since the boundary between `M2` and `te` is a 0-length string, that invisible zero-length character matches and the pattern terminates there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this negative lookahead regex:

```
preg_match_all('/DELIM1((?:(?!DELIM1|DELIM2).)*)DELIM2((?:(?!DELIM1|DELIM2).)*)/',
                $example, $matches);
```

`(?:(?!DELIM1|DELIM2).)*` will match 0 or more of any character that doesn't have `DELIM1` or `DELIM2` at next position.

**Output:**

```
print_r($matches);

    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => DELIM1test1DELIM2test2
                [1] => DELIM1test3DELIM2test4
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => test1
                [1] => test3
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => test2
                [1] => test4
            )        
    )
```